# Application fees error in Stripe Terminal (Direct charge)

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to collect application fees in direct charge concept with Stripe Terminal but Am getting error" Can only apply an application_fee_amount when the PaymentIntent is attempting a direct payment (using an OAuth key or Stripe-Account header)". when i use destination charge its work fine but i want to use direct charge. below code is for destination code.Please help me how i can get application fee in direct charge.

```
public void paymentIntent() {
    PaymentIntentParameters params = new PaymentIntentParameters.Builder()
            .setAmount(usdamount)
            .setCurrency("usd")
            .setApplicationFeeAmount(usdapplicationfee)
            .setDescription("Order#" + orderref)
            .setMetadata(initialMetadata)
            .setOnBehalfOf(accountid)
            .setTransferDataDestination(accountid)
            .build();
    Terminal.getInstance().createPaymentIntent(params, new PaymentIntentCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(PaymentIntent paymentIntent) {
            collecetpayment(paymentIntent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(TerminalException exception) {
            accounterror(exception.getErrorMessage(), exception.getMessage());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it's a little complex, because for direct charges to succeed the [PaymentIntent,
Reader, Location, and Connection](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/connect) must exist on the connected account. That means that you must pass [the Stripe-Account header](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header) when creating these objects.

> If you use direct charges, all Terminal API objects belong to connected accounts.

Here's the flow to create a direct charge with application fee with Terminal:

1. Your server creates the PaymentIntent on the connected account (by passing the Stripe-Account header) & sets the application fee.
2. (p400 only) Your server creates a Location on the connected account
3. (p400 only) Your server registers a Reader to that Location (passing the Stripe-Account header)
4. Your server creates a Connection token on the connected account

Note that steps 2 & 3 only apply to the Verifone reader—the bluetooth-based reader will register itself and your app's current location when integrated with the Stripe Terminal SDK.

After initializing Terminal with the Connection from step 4, you can pass the PaymentIntent from Step1 to Terminal.instance().collectPaymentMethod(), .processPayment(). Because the Connection and PaymentIntent are both attached to the connected account, the Terminal SDK will be able to process the direct charges.

There doesn't seem to be an  example of this in the Stripe docs at the moment, so if you get stuck I'd recommend asking on their IRC channel (#stripe on freenode) or emailing Stripe support.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed this issue. but am getting new error No such payment_intent: 'pi_*******************'. i got client_secret from server and i passed it in retrievePaymentIntent method and am getting error

Comment: If you are using direct charges, you need to pass the account ID when retrieving or confirming the PaymentIntent. It's not clear at what stage you are seeing this error, but regardless "No such <object>: obj_XXXX" is usually an indication that you are working with an object on another account, but did not pass a Stripe-Account header.